# Haskell data structure with efficient inexact lookup by key?

Tags: haskell

I have data keyed by `Data.Time.Calendar.Day` and need to efficiently look it up.  Some dates are missing, when I try to look up by a missing key, I want to get data attached to the closest existing key, somewhat like [std::map::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound).

Any suggestions for existing libraries that can do this?  I searched around for a while and only found maps supporting exact key lookups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check [`Data.Map.Lazy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Lazy.html)? In particular, I guess you could use the functions [`lookupLE`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3alookupLE) and [`lookupGT`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3alookupGT), or similar. The complexity of these functions is *O*(log *n*), and similar functions exist in [`Data.Map.Strict`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Strict.html).

Answer (score 2):

A suitable combination of `Data.Map`'s [`splitLookup`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3AsplitLookup) and [`findMin`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3AfindMin)/[`findMax`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3AfindMax) will do the trick.